# Trying to figure out why the child process's get terminated sooner than they should

Tags: c, process, wait, fork

I am trying to write a program where a parent process would fork n children(node_number of children) and where the children have to carry out a specific task which is the same for every child.

After placing a couple of printf's in my code I realized that there is an error in the for loop in the child processes which is that the for does not terminate at the right place, for example if the code reads, `for(p=0;p<=10; p++)` the printf shows that the process does not count up to more than p=6!

I am really new at this and even though I searched the web I didn't find anything useful! Could someone help me please?

```
#include "ranlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


#define node_number 1 
#define seed1 123455L
#define seed2 54321L
#define floor_rates {{0,1,1},{1,0,1}}
// the floor_rates should be intialized at the beginning and they specify the amount
// of flow rate to a specific destination from a specific node, for example
// floor_rates[k][i] is the amount of data node i has for destination k.
#define numofflows 2

float **diagonalcreation(int matsize, float *matrix)//, float **diagonal)
{
int i;
int j;
int k;
float **diagonal;
diagonal=malloc(sizeof(float *)*matsize);
for(i=0;i<matsize;i++)
{
    diagonal[i]=malloc((sizeof(float))*matsize);
}
for(i=0; i<matsize;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<matsize; j++)
    {
        if(i==j)
        {
            diagonal[i][j]=matrix[i];
        }
        else
        {
            diagonal[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
}

for( k=0;k<matsize; k++)
{
    printf("behnaz hastam\n");
    for(j=0; j<matsize; j++)
    {
        printf("%f\t",diagonal[k][j]);
    }
}
return diagonal;
}


int main()
{
    float c_mean[node_number][node_number];
    pid_t pid[node_number];
    int check;
    check=0;
     //   int index;
     // index=0;
    float c_var[node_number][node_number];
    struct nodes{ 
        float *a;
        float *b;
        float *r;
        int length_r;
        float *s;
        int length_s;
        float **A;
        float **B;
        //right now we have not implemented the DIV protocol but when we do there is a need   for a different variable named seq_number_rec which is the last sequence number recieved.
        //last_seq_number_sent;
        //ack
        float **lambdaprimey_x_x;
        float **lambdax_y_x;
        float lambdax_x_x[numofflows];
        float **t;
        float **ttemp;
        float **tprime;
        float **lambdacomputeprime;
        float lambdacompute[numofflows];
        int *neighbors;
        int length_neighbors;


    } node[node_number];

    int i;
    int j;
    //int numofflows;
    /* srand((unsigned)time(0));
    seed1=random();//12345L;
    seed2=random();//54321L;*/
    setall(seed1,seed2);
    //signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
       for(i=0;i<=node_number-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=i-1; j++)
        {

            c_mean[i][j]=genchi(1.0);
             if (c_mean[i][j]>1)
             {
             c_mean[i][j]=1.0/c_mean[i][j];
             }
             if(i==j)
             {
             c_mean[i][j]=0;
             }
        }

    }
     for(i=0;i<=node_number-1;i++)
     {
     for(j=i; j<=node_number-1; j++)
     {
     c_mean[i][j]=c_mean[j][i];

     }
     }
    //we are assuming that the links are bimodal with a certain probability to be up or  down.
    for(i=0;i<=node_number-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=node_number-1; j++)
        {
            c_var[i][j]=c_mean[i][j]*(1-c_mean[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // pid[0]=fork();

    for(i=0;i<node_number;i++)
    {
        pid[i]=fork();
        if(pid[i]==0)
        {
            int *temp_n=node[i].neighbors;
            float *temp_a=node[i].a;
            float *temp_b=node[i].b;
            float *temp_r=node[i].r;
            float *temp_s=node[i].s;
            //pid[i]=fork();

            int p;
            //The first step is to do the initialization in each process.
            for(p=0; p<=10; p++)
            {
                if(i==0){
                    printf("%d %d %d\n\n\n",p,i, node_number);}
                node[i].length_neighbors=0;

                if(c_mean[i][p]!=0)
                {
                    *temp_n=p;
                    temp_n++;
                    node[i].length_neighbors++;
                    *temp_a=c_var[i][p];
                    temp_a++;
                    *temp_b=c_var[p][p];
                    temp_b++;
                    *temp_r=c_mean[i][p];
                    temp_r++;
                    *temp_s=c_mean[p][i];
                    temp_s++;
                    free(&temp_n);
                    free(&temp_a);
                    free(&temp_b);
                    free(&temp_s);
                    free(&temp_r);
                }

            }


              node[i].A=diagonalcreation(node[i].length_neighbors,node[i].a);//, float    **diagonal)

    /*        for( k=0;k<node[i].neighbors; k++)
            {
                printf("\n");
                for(j=0; j<node[i].neighbors; j++)
                {
                    printf("%f\t",node[i].A[k][j]);
                }
            }
            */
            free(node[i].A);
            printf("behnaaaz");
            exit(0);

        }
        else if(pid[i]<0)
        {
            printf("error_pid");
            break;
        }

    }
    for(i=0;i<node_number;i++)
    {
        if(pid[i]!=0)
        {
            check++;
        }
    }
    if(check==node_number)
    {
        for(i=0;i<node_number;i++)
        {
            wait(NULL);
            printf("waitover");
        }
    }


    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Given `#define node_number 1`, and `for (i = 0; i < node_number; i++)`, it is surprising you get to 6.  Also, call a function for each child; don't stuff so much of the activity into the `main()` program.  Getting process control right is hard enough without mixing it with the computation too.

Answer (score 1):

First, for error-checking, do not use `printf()` ... instead use `fprintf`, and output to `stderr`, since that does not buffer, where-as `stdout` and `printf` do buffer the output, so using those functions with `stdout` will not necessarily print to the console at the point-of-call due to buffering.

Secondly, in your `for` loop you are freeing memory to pointers that it does not appear have been allocated via `malloc()`.  That's going to cause undefined behavior since you can only call `free()` on the same pointer that was returned from a call to `malloc()` ... you can't free-up "part" of an array ... you can only free an entire block of allocated memory at once after you're finished with it.

Third, you are passing to `free()` a pointer to a value that has been allocated on the stack (i.e., `temp_n`, etc.).  So you're actually passing a pointer to an address on the stack that is pointing to an address on the heap to `free()`, not a pointer value to a memory address on the heap which was returned from `malloc()`. Either way though, you still can't deallocate part of an array, which is what it appears you're trying to-do.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using fork(), the child processes do not share data with each other nor with the parent!  You can't set up a data structure in the parent, then use fork() to let child processes fill the data, and finally read the data in the parent.  The child processes each get their individual copy of the data structure which disappears when the child terminates.

To create child processes that share data, you must use pthread_create().